# Infinite Android service restart not working on second time

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, timertask

I'm writing a service that sends a message to a remote server every interval.
I'm using Android 4.4 (KitKat).
The service also has an activity that allows some minimal configuration such as the remote server's URL.

I managed to make the service work, start from boot and restart if killed, but I have some issue with the latter.
If I open the app for the first time, all works well. Killing the app results in a broadcast intent and the service revives (without the activity of course). Now, if I open the app a second time (after the kill and revive), the next time I kill the app, the service does not restart.

My broadcast receiver:

```
public class dynDNSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "dynDNSBroadcastReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Broadcast received, starting dynDNS service");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, dyndns.class));
    }
}
```

My service:

```
public class dyndns extends Service {

    private static String TAG = "dynDNS service";
    public SharedPreferences myPrefs;
    private Handler mainHandler;
    private Timer timer;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startForeground(1, new Notification());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "dynDNS service started");
        mainHandler = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 10000, 10000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        timer.cancel();
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "dynDNS service destroyed");

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("restartService");
        broadcastIntent.setClass(this, dynDNSBroadcastReceiver.class);
        this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
```

Relevant code from my activity:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                Log.d(TAG, serviceClass.getName());
                Log.d (TAG, "Service status: Running");
                return true;
            }
        }
        Log.d (TAG, "Service status: Not running");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(mServiceIntent);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Relevant code form the manifest:

```
 <service
     android:name="com.dyndns.dyndns"
     android:enabled="true" android:process=":externalProcess">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.dyndns.dyndns" />
     </intent-filter>
 </service>

 <receiver android:name="dynDNSBroadcastReceiver"  android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="restartService"/>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: You need to make a notification so that the service starts on the notification thread and cannot be killed even if the app is killed. Example [see this link](https://github.com/NeilSayok/GPS-Car-Locator-System/blob/master/CarLocator4L/app/src/main/java/com/example/neil/carlocator4l/GPS_service.java). Rest will be almost same.

Comment: So, investigating logcat I found my issue (Although I still don't know why it happens): First time I run the app and then kill I see the onPause and onDestroy methods being called. The second time I do that I only see the onPause method. My broadcast intent is sent on the onDestroy method, so, there you go.